# NodeJs SQL query times from database but show different output

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime, timezone

This is time in table column created_at using type timestamp >>>> 2020-05-12 17:17:35

but when I query created_at from table using below code I got different output

it's show me 2020-05-12T10:17:35.000Z instead of 2020-05-12 17:17:35

```
let datedate = null

await pool('select * from my_table where id = ?', [obj.my_table_id])
    .then(async (list) => {
        list = list.map(l => {
            datedate = l.created_at
        })
    })
    .catch((err) => { msg: err })

console.log(datedate)
```

I don't know why it show me different timezone not my local timezone (mine is utc+7)

How can I fix this or how can I convert it to my timezone. thank you

Comment: `timestamp`s in mysql don't have a timezone associated with them.

Comment: "2020-05-12 17:17:35" is not a format supported by ECMA-262, some implementations will treat it as an invalid date. If parsed correctly, it will be treated as local. If you want it treated as UTC, manually parse it (a library can help) or store timestamps in the format supported by ECMA-262, e.g. "2020-05-12T17:17:35Z".

Comment: If your timezone offset is +7, then 2020-05-12T10:17:35.000Z and 2020-05-12 17:17:35 are the same moment in time, just that one is shown as UTC and the other local (to you). Note that the local time is 7 hours later, reflecting your timezone offset of +7.